# Con web scraping en Python, cómo extraer una palabra de un texto?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scraping

Buen día, Estoy tratando de separar una palabra del texto para poder añadirle un "CUALQUIER COSA" en medio del texto y de esa forme me imprima el texto con algo agregado en medio. Hasta el momento solo he logrado imprimir solo el texto completo.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = 'https://monoschinos.com/ver/natsunagu-episodio-12'
page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
eq=soup.find_all('iframe', class_='embed-responsive-item')

for item in soup.select('h1',class_='Title-epi mt-4'):
    print(item.get_text())
```

Comment: Hola, ¿exactamente en que posición o después de que palabra o que criterio sigues para determinar la posición en la que insertar la cadena en la otra?

Comment: Disculpe, Soy algo nuevo en esto. Se refiere a como agregaría el "cualquier cosa" ?  print("cualquiercosa"+(item.get_text())

Comment: Pero tu código ahora muestra `"Natsunagu! 12 Sub Español"`, ¿Cuál sería la salida esperada? Con `print("cualquiercosa"+item.get_text())` concatenas ambas cadenas sin más.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Logre resolverlo quitando el for y separando las palabras con un split y seleccionando cada palabra con [0] y [1], Comparto el codigo.

`item= soup.find('h1',class_='Title-epi mt-4').get_text()
print(item.split(' ')[0]+(" Sub Español - Episodio ")+item.split(' ')[1])`